# No Module named django.core

Tags: python, django

I have updated to latest Django version 1.0.2 after uninstalling my old Django version.But now when I run django-admin.py I get the following error. How can I resolve this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\django-admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core import management
ImportError: No module named django.core
```

Comment: Looks like a 'stale path' issue. Can't say. In the Python shell, are you able to successfully do `import django` and/or `from django.core import management`?

Comment: Yes I am able to do both without any error

Comment: Do you have multiple Python versions installed? How are you invoking django-admin?

Comment: Please run the following:  import sys; print sys.path

Comment: It has been a year and a half now, anyone came up with solution? I encountered this issue too. -_-

Comment: After removing the entire Python directory and installing Python/django again, the problem is gone.

Comment: Remember to run "python setup.py install"

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You must make sure that django is in your PYTHONPATH.

To test, just do a `import django` from a python shell. There should be no output:

```
ActivePython 2.5.1.1 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, May  1 2007, 17:47:05) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>>
```

If you installed django via `setuptools` (`easy_install`, or with the `setup.py` included with django), then check in your `site-packages` if the `.pth` file (`easy-install.pth`, `django.pth`, ...) point to the correct folder.

HIH.

Comment: if u read the comments on his question, he already tried import djago and it works.

Comment: @hasen he probably had django in his local app folder, but did not have django in his pythonpath.

Answer (score 44):

I have the same problem on Windows and it seems I've found the problem. I have both 2.7 and 3.x installed. It seems it has something to do with the associate program of .py:

In commandline type:

> assoc .py

and the result is:

.py=Python.File

which means .py is associated with Python.File

then I tried this:

> ftype Python.File

I got:

Python.File="C:\Python32\python.exe" "%1" %*

which means in commandline .py is associated with my Python 3.2 installation -- and that's why I can't just type "django-admin.py blah blah" to use django.

ALL you need to do is change the association:

> ftype Python.File="C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*

then everythong's okay!

Comment: This helped big time. I had the same issue. Even though I run Python and the version I get is 2.7, when I run a file like C:\test.py the version was running python 3.2. I would like to add one more tip to your solution though. You have to be running the command prompt as an administrator for it to work otherwise you will get this error "Acess is Denied"

Comment: from my point of view, this answer is the mostly helpful to Python newcomers (just like me), who have activated virtualenv or multiple Python installations (especially on Windows). I would like this answer to be at the top of the topic.

Also I think, the Django tutorial should have a note about this case (Python + Windows + VirtualEnv/Multiple Pythons). At the [first part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/) of tutorial it just says to type `django-admin.py startproject mysite`, which is very implicit.

Comment: It helped me a lot too.. great answer !!

Comment: Awesome.  I also found a blog that fixes the issue without permanently changing the file association.
http://djangonautlostinspace.wordpress.com/2012/04/16/django-and-windows/

Comment: I voted up for this answer, but I didn't have a problem with different versions of python, instead, it was a conflict between the main python installation and the one on `virtualenv`. The answer guided me to the solution of running `python django-admin.py` instead of just `django-admin.py`

Comment: small caveat, ftype Python.File will yield access denied if you don't run cmd as admin

Answer (score 25):

You can get around this problem by providing the full path to your django-admin.py file

```
python c:\python25\scripts\django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

Comment: Thank you! But in my case I Wrote "python3" instead of "python".
Solved!

Answer (score 16):

I encountered this problem today, it turned out that I had C:\Python26 in my path and .py files were associated to Python 3.1. Repairing the proper version of Python, either through Programs and Features or by running the .msi, will fix the associations.

Comment: This was the problem for me, too.  NOTE: don't be fooled if running the python command shows version 2.X.  Executing the django file could still be linked to the 3.1 executable.

Comment: Note that this refers to Windows' file associations. In Windows 7 this can be changed in Control Panel > Programs > Default Programs > Associate a file...

Comment: Looks like this can't be fixed manually like I thought. Command line arguments end up broken. Just reinstall Python.

Comment: I had a similar issue where django couldn't find the `core` library, but the issue for me was that cygwin was using what I assume is it's builtin python (2.6), instead of the python 2.7 that I have installed outside of cygwin, so my solution was to use `cmd.exe` instead of cygwin to `django-admin.py startproject`

Answer (score 12):

It was a PYTHONPATH environment variable issue for me, as others mentioned above, but noone has really shown how to set it for people that could use the extra instruction.

**Linux (bash)**

I set this variable in my bashrc file in my home folder (.bashrc is the file for me since my shell is /bin/bash).

```
vim ~/.bashrc
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
source ~/.bashrc
```

The path should be wherever your django source is.  Mine is located at /usr/local/python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django, so I just specified /usr/local/python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages without the django portion.

**OSX**

On OSX the path is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and you can add it to `/etc/profile`:

```
sudo echo "PYTHONPATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH" >> /etc/profile
source /etc/profile
```

Comment: whe i use zsh it's showing `zsh: permission denied: /etc/profile`

Answer (score 9):

I'm sure it's related to something incorrect in my setup, but it works properly if I do this:

```
python c:\Python26\scripts\django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

Comment: I had the same problem and this worked for me too... anyone knows why?

Comment: I found the answer, I've python3 and python27 in the same machine, it's a windows one. If I execute the command c:\>python in the console, it calls python27, so django exists, but if I execute a python script this way: "c:\>test.py" it gets executed with python3, so the error (I'm used to linux, I still feel I'm lost in windows env handling)

Comment: I have Python 2.5 and Python 2.7 This worked for me too! Earlier I was just executing on the cmd, `django-admin.py startproject mysite` and I did what Noad above wrote, but found my association of .py is with Python 2.7, so I'm not sure why this particularly works.

Comment: on windows-virtualenv, must use this syntax.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Windows, then Don't run with 'django-admin.py', since this will call your outer python.exe to execute and it cannot read into the django inside the virtual environemnt. Try 'python django-admin.py' to use your python.exe inside your environment.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me with bitnami djangostack:

```
python apps\django\django\bin\django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in windows xp. The reason was i installed multiple python versions(2.6,3.2).windows's PATH is set correctly to python26, but the .py file is associated with python32. I want the .py file is associated with python26.To solve it, the easit way is to right click the *.py(such as django-admin.py),choose "open with"->"choose program..."->"Browse..." (select c:\python26\python.ext)->"Ok". Then we can run django-admin.py in the cmd without the need for the expatiatory prefix "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\django\bin".

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old question, but I just had the same problem,
in my case, it was because the I am using virtualenv with django, but .py file extensions in Windows are associated with the main Python installation, so running the django-admin.py are directly from the command prompt causes it run with the main Python installation without django installed.

So, since i dont know if there is any hash pound equivalent in Windows, I worked around this by running python followed by the full path of the django-admin.py, or you can also modify the virtualenv batch script to change the file associations and change it back when you deactivate it (although I am not sure how to do it, as I am not really familiar with batch script).

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and recalled that I had installed iPython the previous afternoon.  I uninstalled iPython and the problem went away.  Incidentally, I am working with virtualenv.  I had installed iPython in the system-wide site-packages directory, so I just re-installed iPython inside each virtualenv that I am using.  After installing iPython yesterday I had noticed a warning message (from version 0.13 of iPython) that it had detected that I was using virtualenv and that if I ran into any trouble I should install iPyton inside each virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

If your path variables are correct and from the python shell you can do: from django.core import management , make sure you're including "python" before "django-admin.py" as such: python django-admin.py startproject thelittlethings

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution though not the most elegant is to copy the django-admin.py from the Scripts folder. The Scripts folder will be found under your Python installation . On my computer it is in C:\Python26\Scripts. Then paste the django-admin.py into the folder you are trying to run the file from.
It is true that the use of the System path will give flexibility. This is a particular solution if you are in a hurry. Then type for instance python django-admin.py startproject fluffyteaspoons and you will create the project fluffyteaspoons

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I'm on OS X Lion and I've installed Python with [homebrew](https://brew.sh/)
I was getting the same error, but none of the solutions posted here helped me. In my case I just had to edit the script:

```
vim /usr/local/share/python/django-admin.py
```

And I noticed that the first line was wrong, as it was pointing to the system's python installation:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

I just modified it to point to homebrew's installation:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
```

And it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

This worked on Mac OS X

In the terminal run python
In python:
  import sys
  print sys.path

Look for the site packages path.  I found this in the output of sys.path:
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages'

exit python.  Find where your current site-packages are.  Mine were at /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages

Now be careful: Check the content of site-packages to be sure it is empty. That is, directory /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages should be empty, or just contain a readme file. If it is, delete that directory, because you are now about to make a symlink.

ln -s /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages

If you don't delete the folder you will put the symlink in the folder.

Other options are to add the path to the sys.path. I elected the symlink route because I have a couple of versions of python, I don't want several versions of Django, and just wanted to point to the known working copy.

Answer (score 1):

I just got the same ImportError in Windows Vista having Python 2.7 and 3.2 installed and using virualenv with Python 2.7 and Django 1.4.3.

I changed the file association of .py files in Explorer from 3.2 to 2.7. Rightclicking a .py file and changing settings. I still got the ImportError.

I ran `cmd.exe` as an administrator and copypasted the earlier `ftype` stuff. After an error, noted that double quotes don't get copied correctly from browser to cmd. Rewrote the command in cmd, but I still got the ImportError.

In root of the actived virtual environment, I explicitly gave the `python` command and the path to django-admin.py from there.
`(env_p27) C:\Users\Gemmu\env_p27>python .\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject mysite`

That worked.

Thanks for all the help for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because I ran `pip` as `sudo` while my virtualenv is setup to not import outside site packages so Django was installed for the root user but not in the virtualenv, even though I had virtualenv activated when I ran sudo.

Solution switch to root, activate venv then do pip install.

Answer (score 1):

To tack on to what [lichenbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1376351/lichenbo) said... If you are using Windows, then Don't run with 'django-admin.py'...

I'm running inside a virtual environment, so the path and command to create a new project looks like:

```
(DjangoEnv)  C:\users\timreilly\Envs\django\Scripts\django-admin.exe startproject myproject
```

DjangoEnv is the name of my virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, an install script failed to set world read/execute permissions :)
Do this:

```
sudo find  /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django -type d -exec chmod go+rx {} \;
sudo find  /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django -type f -exec chmod go+r {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting the question and answers. I have two versions of Python installed, but root was pointing to the /usr/bin version, and I wanted to use the 2.7 version of Python in /usr/local/bin. After rebuilding/reinstalling Django and mysqldb, all is well and I'm not getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Small quick fix is just to create symlink `ln -s $SOMEWHERE/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/ ./django`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it was clear that I had a `PYTHONPATH` configuration issue. The solution is quite simple, just create a file with this name `django.pth` in your `PYTHONHOME\Lib\site-packages` directory where `PYTHONHOME` is the directory where Python is installed (mine is: C:\Python27). Add the following line to the `django.pth` file:

```
PYTHONHOME\Lib\site-packages\django
```

Of course you have to change `PYTHONHOME` to your Python's installation directory as I explained.

Note that you can edit the `django.pth` to include any directory that you want to be included in the `PYTHONPATH`. Actually, you can name that file as you wish, `path.pth` for example if you want it to be more general and to include several directory paths.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. I do something radical. I unistall python and I delete from Environment `Variables/PATH this: ;C:\Python26\Scripts;C:\Python26.`
And Its work...
I had your problem before.

Answer (score 0):

I realized this happen because I didn't run `python setup.py install`. That setup the environment.

Answer (score 0):

After reading a lot I found a solution that works for me.

I have

```
 django version 1.9.2
```

1. Set all system variable in "path".No duplicate copy in user variable nor in the PYTHONPATH .
   [image]
2. Then set Value in regedit

[image]

3. made a virtualenv in desired folder by command

   virtualenv VENV
4. And finally in cmd

***used command***

```
django-admin.py startproject MySite

***and not this***

python django-admin.py startproject MySite
```

at the root folder of the "VENV"

And It worked