# Django startup problems

Tags: python, django

This is something similar to what's posted here: [No Module named django.core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312549/no-module-named-django-core)

To reiterate, I'm getting this error on running "django-admin.py startproject mysite"(without the double quotes):

```
C:\Documents and Settings\fixavier\Desktop>django-admin.py startproject mysite
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\apps\django\django\bin\django-admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core import management
ImportError: No module named django.core
```

But the error still exists! Please help.
OS:Windows
Installed django using BitNami Django stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you try to import django from the Python shell? Type `python` at a command prompt, then type `import django` at the next prompt. I'm not familiar with BitNami, but you might want to consider just installing Django the normal way. Otherwise you're going to have a hard time getting answers to issues via Google. It's not hard to install on Windows. You can get a [binary installer for Python](http://www.python.org/download/), then install Django according to the [instructions in the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/install/#topics-install).

Bonus points (and not as complicated as it sounds): To make Python package installation fairly painless, you can then install [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) (or you can install pip first and then run `pip install django`). In order to install pip, you'll need [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#windows). Once setuptools is installed, you should be able to do `easy_install pip`, but that's the only time you should ever use `easy_install` as pip's a much better product.

Comment: "import django" - is giving errors too!
"ImportError: No module named django"

Comment: I would definitely suggest just installing Django properly. The issue must be that BitNami put your django folders in a location that is not in your PYTHONPATH. Just install pip (after setuptools) and run `pip install django` to get Django properly set up.

BTW, what database are you going to be using? You'll need the Python  bindings for it. MySQL ones are at http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/

Comment: hmmm.Must be.Started installing via the links that you just put up.Let's see.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the location of your django install to your PATH settings. Instant Django might also be an option for you http://www.instantdjango.com/.