# Python + Django + VirtualEnv + Windows

Tags: python, windows, django, virtualenv

I had some problem on installing python + virtualenv + django and need help.

System: Windows 7, 64b

What i do?
**1) Installed Python 2.7.2 (32bits)
2) Installed SetupTools (32 bits)
3) Installed VirtualEnv**

```
E:\APPZ\Console2>C:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install.exe virtualenv
```

**4) Created virtualenv:**

```
E:\APPZ\Console2>virtualenv E:\CODE\wamp\www\AMBIENTES\env
```

**5) Fine, now I created a ".bat" to use my env and put then in C:\Windows.**

C:\Windows\python.bat

```
cmd.exe /k E:\CODE\wamp\www\AMBIENTES\env\Scripts\activate.bat
```

So far so good
Now I executed the python.bat and installed django:

```
E:\APPZ\Console2>python

E:\APPZ\Console2>cmd.exe /k E:\CODE\wamp\www\AMBIENTES\env\Scripts\activate.bat
(env) E:\APPZ\Console2>cd E:\CODE\wamp\www\AMBIENTES\Django-1.2.7

(env) E:\CODE\wamp\www\AMBIENTES\Django-1.2.7>python setup.py install
django installed (1.2.7) successfully.
```

And now, the problem:

```
(env) E:\CODE\wamp\www\AMBIENTES\Django-1.2.7>E:\CODE\wamp\www\AMBIENTES\env\Scripts\django-admin.py --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\CODE\wamp\www\AMBIENTES\env\Scripts\django-admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core import management
ImportError: No module named django.core

(env) E:\CODE\wamp\www\AMBIENTES\Django-1.2.7>
```

-

Does anyone know what I can do about it?

Comment: What happens if instead of installing from source you use `pip install Django==1.2.7` or `easy_install Django==1.2.7`? (pip/easy_install are inherently aware of virtual environments when installing, the setup.py script for Django may not be)

Comment: don't name your file python.bat!  that's just asking for trouble and name clashes with the real `python.exe`.

Comment: @MaxFerreira, if you've found my answer usefull, please mark it as "Accepted Answer"

Answer (score 15):

I know this question is old and maybe not actual anymore for author. But as far as it appears at Google's top, I would leave the answer that helped me.

Basically the correct answer is [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10070104/592377) for the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312549/no-module-named-django-core).

Strictly speaking the wrong Python installation is called when you execute `django-admin.py --version`. in order to check which Python you use in the case, type `ftype Python.File` in "command line". If it's not the virtualenv's one, then you could reassociate the default Python:

`ftype Python.File="E:\CODE\wamp\www\AMBIENTES\env\Scripts\python.exe" "%1" %*`

Or unset the file association (from cmd.exe):

```
assoc .py=
ftype Python.File=
```

After you reassociate the `.py` extension program, you should specify full path to execute Python files:

`E:\CODE\wamp\www\AMBIENTES\env\Scripts\python.exe E:\CODE\wamp\www\AMBIENTES\env\Scripts\django-admin.py --version`

Or if you want, you could edit virtualenv's `activate.bat` to put specific `.py` association, using `assoc` and `ftype` command line utils, mentioned above.

Comment: Need to use full path to the virtualenv version of python -- thanks for explicit example!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that using `python setup.py install` with the Django source is installing Django in your primary site-packages/dist-packages path instead of that of your virtual environment.

Instead, use pip or easy_install:

```
$ pip install Django==1.2.7  --OR -- $ easy_install Django==1.2.7
```

If you can't directly download from PyPi (corporate firewall, etc.) you can use the source you already have by modifying the command slightly:

```
$ pip install -f file:///E/CODE/wamp/www/AMBIENTES/ Django==1.2.7
```

(Converted Windows path may need some tweaking. I think that's right, but it's been awhile)