# How to create a Django project folder

Tags: django, windows, command-line

I'm following a tutorial on Django and I'm suppose to create a folder via Windows Command Prompt (the turorial asks to type the following at `C:\`):

```
django-admin.py startproject django_bookmarks
```

and I should get the following folder with these files:

```
django_bookmarks/
     __init__.py manage.py settings.py urls.py
```

I tried at c:\, at c:\Django-1.4.2.

and I get the same following error messages:

"Django-1.4.2 is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Note: Django is properly installed. I made a test on python and it shows Django's version properly.

How do I create that folder?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try using the following command (if Python-2.7.X is your interpreter, and if you have not installed Django in a virtualenv):

> C:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject django_bookmarks

If you have installed Django in a virtualenv, replace the part `C:\Python27` by the path to this virtualenv.

If you have installed several versions of Python, Have a look at this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10070104/493211)

Comment: It works perfectly!! Note for those who experience the same ordeal: I uninstalled Python3.3, intalled Python2.7, and make sure that PYTHONPATH is clean. You can do that by typing "echo %PYTHONPATH%" in Windows Command Prompt. And I reinstalled Django and followed Marc-Olivier Titeux' advice.

Comment: This answer is good !!!
Just paste the path to your django-admin.py file. 

It works for me.

Answer (score 4):

`$` is not a part of the command, it is a command prompt. It indicates that the command should be entered in a command line interpreter.

The command itself should start with `django-admin.py`:

```
django-admin.py startproject django_bookmarks
```

Comment: Hello , thanks for editing! even without the $ sign I get an error message "unrecognized.." and I tried at c:\, at c:\Django(main folder)...

Comment: @Sylvain No problem. Did omitting the `$` help?

Comment: unfortunately, omitting $ did not help

Comment: yeap:"Django-admin.py is not recognized as an internal command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: This means Django is not installed properly, I guess. `django-admin.py` should be available. But I haven't tried it on Windows, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In case if someone still needs, you have to have *python* in front of that:

```
directory1\directory2>python django-admin.py startproject django_bookmarks.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command after activating your virtual environment.

```
django-admin startproject project_name
```

then to create a new app run this command:

```
python manage.py startapp app_name
```