# django-admin.py error: from django.core import management ImportError: No module named django.core

Tags: python, django, windows, virtualenv

I have the following error when I tried to run django-admin.py under windows8. I also have python27 installed and virtualenvwrapper-win

```
(juice) C:\>pip freeze
Django==1.6.5

(juice) C:\>django-admin.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mohamed\Envs\juice\Scripts\django-admin.py", line 2, in <module
>
    from django.core import management
ImportError: No module named django.core

(juice) C:\>
```

Itried the following solutions, but none is working:

Modified the read-only permission on the virtualenv folder
checked the path as of follow:

```
(juice) C:\>python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> for path in sys.path:
...    print path
...

C:\Users\Mohamed\Envs\juice\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\Mohamed\Envs\juice\lib\site-packages\pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg
C:\Python27
C:\Python27\DLLs
C:\Python27\Lib
C:\
C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip
C:\Users\Mohamed\Envs\juice\DLLs
C:\Users\Mohamed\Envs\juice\lib
C:\Users\Mohamed\Envs\juice\lib\plat-win
C:\Users\Mohamed\Envs\juice\lib\lib-tk
C:\Users\Mohamed\Envs\juice\Scripts
C:\Users\Mohamed\Envs\juice
C:\Users\Mohamed\Envs\juice\lib\site-packages
>>>
```

Also I checked the path sys variable and it has c:\python27 listed.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

========================================================
Based on suggestion below I added PYTHONPATH system variable and tried django-admin.py and I had the same error!
So at this point I am thinking may be I should install django outside the virtualenv. However if I do that I am pretty sure that Django-admin.py will work, however if defeats the whole purpose of using virtualenv to manage python packages.....

Comment: Do you have python 2 and 3 installed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No Module named django.core](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312549/no-module-named-django-core)