# Run django-admin

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django and I would like to follow this tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/

Unfortunately, `django-admin` is not in my path.

When I try to run the `django-admin.py` script directly, I have the following error:

```
$ /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core import management
ImportError: No module named django.core
```

Here is my configuration:

- System: *macOS 10.13*
- Python: 3.7.0 (installed via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)
- Django: 2.1.4

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312549/no-module-named-django-core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think You don’t install django correctly. If you are highly new in django then follow these steps to setup your clean and new project environment

Create your project folder

```
mkdir myProject
```

Open this Project Folder

```
cd myProject
```

Create virtual environment

```
python3 -m venv env
```

Now, active this virtual environment

```
source env/bin/activate
```

It’s time to install the Django

```
pip install django
```

Create your first project

```
django-admin startproject myProject
```

Open this Project

```
 cd myProject
```

Open your server to check it either it’s work successfully or not

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: Most Welcome 

Answer (score 0):

First check if django is installed by running `python -c "import django"`. If that is successful check if django-admin command is in your python path. If you are using a virtual environment check under virtual environment/bin/. If there is no file such as django-admin then the first solution would be to try reinstalling django. Same case if you are working outside a virtual environment. 
If none of the above solves it then check  if you have both python 2 and 3. If you do check whether .py files are being associated to python 2 instead of python3.

Comment: django-admin is not in my path but when I try to launch it from my location (like I do in my post), I have an error so I don't think adding `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/bin` would help in anyway.