# There is no module django.core when starting a project

Tags: python, django

Hi am struggling for over 12 hrs with python 2.7, I was working with python 3.7 so i decided to change to 2.7 for a certain reason ,so i uninstalled 3.7 and installed 2.7 But after activating the virtual environment cant start a project with this error.
I went through all the procedures [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312549/no-module-named-django-core)  but i could not fix the problem.
The strange thing I tried to install django outside the virtual environment later seems to work fine 
but i think this is inappropriate help out

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\cipher>pip install virtualenv
Collecting virtualenv
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
Successfully installed virtualenv-16.5.0
C:\Users\cipher>virtualenv market
New python executable in C:\Users\cipher\market\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.

C:\Users\cipher>cd market

C:\Users\cipher\market> .\Scripts\activate

(market) C:\Users\cipher\market>pip install django==1.5.4
Collecting django==1.5.4
Installing collected packages: django
Successfully installed django-1.5.4

(market) C:\Users\cipher\market>django-admin.py startproject market
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cipher\market\Scripts\django-admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core import management
ImportError: No module named django.core

(market) C:\Users\cipher\market>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312549/no-module-named-django-core

Comment: I have tried it all

Comment: Why are you installing a version of Django that's more than six years old?

Comment: just wanted to keep up with a certain tutorial though even the latest version doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Even if you received the message of successful installation, you should double check if this is indeed the case (in a python shell launched from market, run `import django` to see if any error is thrown). You could anyway try re-installing it. If no issue with the installation, maybe prefixing the commands that use .py files with `python` will help as shown on [this page](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/1.5.x/faq/troubleshooting.html#running-virtualenv-on-windows).