# ImportError: No module named django.core even I getting when I am importing django in python console

Tags: python, django

I had recently updated my Django version from `1.11` to `3.0`. when I want to create a project using python-admin startproject mysite I am getting error as

> ImportError: No module named django.core

I tried importing the Django in python3 console it is working.

Comment: can you add your error traceback?

Comment: (venv) nyros@nyros:~/django$ django-admin startproject mysite
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/django-admin", line 18, in <module>
    from django.core import management
ImportError: No module named django.core

Comment: Have you used pip with root? If yes please use simple pip

Comment: @ foo-bar it is the traceback in console

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312549/no-module-named-django-core]    Please check this

Comment: @ foo-bar i didnt understand your point.

Comment: @ foo-bar i had used pip3 for installing django

Comment: I think you are using sudo pip3 so it installed outside of virtualenv.

Comment: Now what should I do @ Mishra

Comment: But when i see in virtualenv by pip3 freeze command I am getting the django as available package

Comment: Please delete existing virtualenv and create new virtualenv, activate that virtualenv and install using only pip3

Comment: @ Mishra still I am getting the same error

Comment: have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312549/no-module-named-django-core

Comment: @ Mishra yes I can import django it is done

Answer (score 0):

Try using django-admin instead of python-admin. I made a new virtual environment, downloaded django via pip and `django-admin startproject myapp` worked. Don't forget to activate the virtual environment